# Getting Microsoft Graph Lifecycle Policies not working with Application permissions

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have tried creating an Azure Function that applies a Group Lifecycle Policy to a specific group, but it fails with Application permissions.

Using username and password authentication, this works without a problem.

```java
public static string GetAccessTokenForUser(string resourceUri, string aadDomain, string userName, string password)
    {
        var powershellClientId = "12128f48-ec9e-42f0-b203-ea49fb6af367";
        var azureADAuthority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{aadDomain}/oauth/v2/authorize";
        var userCreds = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(azureADAuthority, true);
        var authResult = AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions.AcquireTokenAsync(authContext, resourceUri, powershellClientId, userCreds).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return authResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

When using ClientId en ClientSecret it always returns 401 Unauthorized error.

```java
public static string GetAccessTokenForClientId(string resourceUri, string aadDomain, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        var azureADAuthority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{aadDomain}/oauth/v2/authorize";
        var clientCreds = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(azureADAuthority, true);
        var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientCreds).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return authResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

Then I do a Get Request using the Access token from the previous function

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groupLifecyclePolicies
```

Documentation at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/grouplifecyclepolicy_list states that Application Permissions should work. Access token contains the required scopes, I checked that.

Can anybody confirm?

EDIT 03/05/2018: Since last week, it seems this is working again per documentation. I currently am able to execute all the lifecycle releated requests through my Application Permissions.

Comment: Can you add details like code, config files or anything that could help the community solve your question ?

Comment: I added code samples.

Comment: Since last week, it seems this is working again per documentation. I currently am able to execute all the lifecycle releated requests through my Application Permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same problem - working on application used to manage groups in O365 working on limited user permissions and executing O365 API requests under App permissions.

I tested app working under application permissions (with Directory.ReadWrite.All) and it worked fine back in ~mid Dec. Unfortunately, when tested yesterday, it failed with missing privileges error.

I managed to find [this commit](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/commit/463d4fd20a78d728fb635f9b370429cb1aead027#diff-ef94740d33c57e036dad799d2eb6f7e4) to Graph API documentation, which shows what happened.

Can anyone from Graph API team tell if you plan to return this feature in any time soon? This has a lot of valid uses.